# Accessing JSON value from nested list in C#

Tags: c#, json, nested

I am trying to loop through some JSON to create some variables using a dictionary.

Here are the definitions that I am using:

```
public class Customfield10002
{
      public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public List<Customfield10002> customfield_10002 { get; set; }
}

public class Issue
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}
```

The following code validates fine.

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);

foreach (var issue in myDeserializedClass.issues)
            {
                string id = issue.id.ToString();
                string key = issue.key.ToString();
                string summary = issue.fields.summary.ToString();
            {
```

But when I include the following string field, it fails validation

```
string creatoremail = issue.fields.customfield_10002.name.ToString();
```

The error is:

> 'List<ITSDWorklogs.Customfield10002' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type"
> 'List<ITSDWorklogs.Customfield10002' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I access the value from this nested list?

Any help greatly appreciated.

UPDATED with JSON

```
        {
      "expand": "names,schema",
      "startAt": 0,
      "maxResults": 1,
      "total": 151,
      "issues": [
        {
          "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
          "id": "10210",
          "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/10210",
          "key": "ITSD-202",
          "fields": {
            "statuscategorychangedate": "2021-01-25T20:12:11.922+0000",
            "issuetype": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issuetype/10003",
              "id": "10003",
              "description": "For customer support issues. Created by Jira Service Desk.",
              "iconUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10308&avatarType=issuetype",
              "name": "Support",
              "subtask": false,
              "avatarId": 10308
            },
            "timespent": null,
            "customfield_10030": null,
            "customfield_10031": {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Time to resolution",
              "_links": {
                "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/10210/sla/1"
              },
              "completedCycles": [],
              "ongoingCycle": {
                "startTime": {
                  "iso8601": "2021-01-25T20:12:11+0000",
                  "jira": "2021-01-25T20:12:11.592+0000",
                  "friendly": "Yesterday 08:12",
                  "epochMillis": 1611605531592
                },
                "breachTime": {
                  "iso8601": "2021-02-11T14:30:00+0000",
                  "jira": "2021-02-11T14:30:00.000+0000",
                  "friendly": "11/Feb/21 02:30",
                  "epochMillis": 1613053800000
                },
                "breached": false,
                "paused": false,
                "withinCalendarHours": false,
                "goalDuration": {
                  "millis": 432000000,
                  "friendly": "120h"
                },
                "elapsedTime": {
                  "millis": 0,
                  "friendly": "0m"
                },
                "remainingTime": {
                  "millis": 432000000,
                  "friendly": "120h"
                }
              }
            },
            "project": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/10000",
              "id": "10000",
              "key": "ITSD",
              "name": "Customer Service Desk",
              "projectTypeKey": "service_desk",
              "simplified": false,
              "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?pid=10000&avatarId=10412",
                "24x24": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&s=small&pid=10000&avatarId=10412",
                "16x16": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&s=xsmall&pid=10000&avatarId=10412",
                "32x32": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&s=medium&pid=10000&avatarId=10412"
              }
            },
            "customfield_10032": {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Time to first response",
              "_links": {
                "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request/10210/sla/2"
              },
              "completedCycles": [],
              "ongoingCycle": {
                "startTime": {
                  "iso8601": "2021-01-25T20:12:11+0000",
                  "jira": "2021-01-25T20:12:11.592+0000",
                  "friendly": "Yesterday 08:12",
                  "epochMillis": 1611605531592
                },
                "breachTime": {
                  "iso8601": "2021-01-26T12:30:00+0000",
                  "jira": "2021-01-26T12:30:00.000+0000",
                  "friendly": "Today 12:30",
                  "epochMillis": 1611664200000
                },
                "breached": false,
                "paused": false,
                "withinCalendarHours": false,
                "goalDuration": {
                  "millis": 14400000,
                  "friendly": "4h"
                },
                "elapsedTime": {
                  "millis": 0,
                  "friendly": "0m"
                },
                "remainingTime": {
                  "millis": 14400000,
                  "friendly": "4h"
                }
              }
            },
            "fixVersions": [],
            "customfield_10034": {
              "languageCode": "en",
              "displayName": "English"
            },
            "resolution": null,
            "customfield_10037": null,
            "customfield_10027": null,
            "customfield_10028": null,
            "customfield_10029": null,
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "workratio": -1,
            "lastViewed": "2021-01-25T20:12:11.936+0000",
            "watches": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/ITSD-202/watchers",
              "watchCount": 1,
              "isWatching": true
            },
            "created": "2021-01-25T20:12:11.592+0000",
            "customfield_10020": null,
            "customfield_10021": null,
            "customfield_10022": null,
            "customfield_10023": null,
            "priority": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/priority/3",
              "iconUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
              "name": "Medium",
              "id": "3"
            },
            "customfield_10024": null,
            "customfield_10025": null,
            "labels": [],
            "customfield_10026": [],
            "customfield_10016": null,
            "customfield_10017": null,
            "customfield_10018": {
              "hasEpicLinkFieldDependency": false,
              "showField": false,
              "nonEditableReason": {
                "reason": "PLUGIN_LICENSE_ERROR",
                "message": "The Parent Link is only available to Jira Premium users."
              }
            },
            "customfield_10019": "0|i0013b:",
            "timeestimate": null,
            "versions": [],
            "assignee": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=12345678912345678912345",
              "accountId": "12345678912345678912345",
              "emailAddress": "first.last@xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk",
              "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "24x24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "16x16": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "32x32": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png"
              },
              "displayName": "First Last",
              "active": true,
              "timeZone": "Europe/London",
              "accountType": "atlassian"
            },
            "updated": "2021-01-25T20:12:14.321+0000",
            "status": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/status/10001",
              "description": "This was auto-generated by Jira Service Desk during workflow import",
              "iconUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/images/icons/status_generic.gif",
              "name": "Waiting for support",
              "id": "10001",
              "statusCategory": {
                "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/statuscategory/4",
                "id": 4,
                "key": "indeterminate",
                "colorName": "yellow",
                "name": "In Progress"
              }
            },
            "components": [],
            "customfield_10050": null,
            "customfield_10051": null,
            "timeoriginalestimate": null,
            "customfield_10052": null,
            "customfield_10053": null,
            "description": null,
            "customfield_10010": null,
            "customfield_10014": null,
            "customfield_10015": null,
            "customfield_10005": null,
            "customfield_10049": null,
            "customfield_10006": null,
            "customfield_10007": null,
            "security": null,
            "customfield_10008": null,
            "customfield_10009": null,
            "summary": "Barry Test",
            "creator": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=12345678912345678912345",
              "accountId": "12345678912345678912345",
              "emailAddress": "first.last@xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk",
              "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "24x24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "16x16": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "32x32": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png"
              },
              "displayName": "First Last",
              "active": true,
              "timeZone": "Europe/London",
              "accountType": "atlassian"
            },
            "customfield_10040": null,
            "customfield_10041": null,
            "customfield_10042": null,
            "customfield_10043": null,
            "reporter": {
              "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=12345678912345678912345",
              "accountId": "12345678912345678912345",
              "emailAddress": "first.last@xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk",
              "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "24x24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "16x16": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png",
                "32x32": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2758e009bbe7f2348bfdf52d653b6a2b?d=https%3A%2F%2Favatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net%2Finitials%2FBE-1.png"
              },
              "displayName": "First Last",
              "active": true,
              "timeZone": "Europe/London",
              "accountType": "atlassian"
            },
            "customfield_10044": null,
            "customfield_10000": "{}",
            "customfield_10001": null,
            "customfield_10045": null,
            "customfield_10046": null,
            "customfield_10002": [
              {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk",
                "_links": {
                  "self": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/4"
                }
              }
            ],
            "customfield_10003": null,
            "customfield_10047": null,
            "customfield_10048": null,
            "customfield_10004": null,
            "customfield_10038": null,
            "customfield_10039": null,
            "environment": null,
            "duedate": null,
            "progress": {
              "progress": 0,
              "total": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: `issue.fields.customfield_10002` is a list. A list doesn't have a property called "name". Each element might though.

Comment: can you add the json to the question?

Comment: @Sajid Thanks for looking, JSON added

Comment: @user3580480 if you have always one element in array, you can use Linq : `issue.fields.customfield_10002.FirstOrDefaul()?.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LINQ for enumerate over *Customfield10002* list:

```
var createOrEmail = issue.fields.customfield_10002.Select(c=>c.name).DefaultIfEmpty("").Aggregate((s, s1) => $"{s}, {s1}");
```

Comment: I'm getting "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: just use **DefaultIfEmpty()**. I update my answer

Comment: it has value "xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk" (from json)

Answer (score 1):

This should work as suggested by @gunr2171

```
string creatoremail = "";
foreach (var names in issue.fields.customfield_10002)
{
    creatoremail = names.name.ToString();
}
```

or by Sajid

```
string creatoremail = issue.fields.customfield_10002.FirstOrDefault().name.ToString();
```

Regards

Comment: i think, in this case, you can use `FirstOrDefault` instead loop.

Comment: It should be tagged as *linq* as well

Comment: gunr2171 code was wrong. Edited just now. Added Sajid's code as well